# what's the acknowledgement number after retransmitting the missing segment

Tags: tcp

I was reading a textbook which describes TCP fast tetransmit, below is a picture
[image]

**If the TCP sender receives three duplicate ACKs for the same data, it takes this as an indication that the segment following the segment that has been ACKed three times has been lost.**

My question is, when host B receives the retransmit packet(sequence=100) and prepares the ack packet to be sent to host A, what's the ack number will host B put into, is the ack number 120 or 157?

Comment: The acknowledgement number is the next expected segment, and it acknowledges everything prior to the number.

Comment: @Zac67 yes, I have accepted it as answer. could you answer this question please?

Comment: @RonMaupin is the ack number 120 or 157?

Comment: What do you think is the next expected segment? That number is the acknowledgement number.

Comment: @amjad Reread the linked answer, paragraph "Meanwhile..." - that's the exact answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

After the events in your diagram, Host B will acknowledge with ACK=157.

However, this diagram contains several errors that might prove confusing.  Most importantly, if the TCP connection doesn't have Selective ACK, it will re-transmit not only the 20 bytes beginning with SEQ=100; it will also re-transmit everything after that, because it doesn't know any better.  It shouldn't send four different segments, though; it should re-transmit one merged segment that is 20+15+6+16 bytes.  The re-transmit you see is wrong unless SACK is present, in which case, a lot more relevant data will be present in the pictured ACKs.

Comment: "_Host B will acknowledge with ACK=141_" No, Host B already has 141, so it will acknowledge that with the next expected segment number.

Comment: "_The very first ACK sent by Host B is pictured incorrectly as well (wrong ACK number.)_" The very first ACK is correct. The acknowledgement number is the next expected segment number, and it acknowledges everything prior to that segment number, so the diagram is correct.

Comment: "_The acknowledgment mechanism employed is cumulative so that an acknowledgment of sequence number X indicates that all octets up to but not including X have been received._"

Comment: Oops!  Corrected.